# Logic Tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

**True/Flase**:
**if** a,b,c ⊨ d 
**so** at least one of this term is tautology: a→d **or** b→d **or** c→d

Maybe someone know how to proof that?

Thanks for help and have a good day!

Comment: What do you mean by "d is supposed to be false"? Who supposes that and why?

Comment: In my opinion this argument is False. so given  a,b,c ⊨ d, and a,b,c can be contradiction and when 'd' can be False/Ture doesn't matter. if a,b,c is false so 'd' have to be False also in that case.

Comment: @KfirWilfand You seem to be contradicting yourself. First you say that it doesn't matter what $d$ is, then you say it is false, (both conclusions under the same assumption). What is it then?

Comment: If $0\to d$ is true, then you can't conclude whether $d$ is false or true, that's correct.

Comment: if you have False→d ,d can be false or true doesn't matter right? since everthing thing can cames from conclusions. so a,b,c if False 'd' can be whatever you like. and if I want one of this term to be tautology it's can happend only if  'd' is False

Comment: Actually i'm a little bit stuck. What do you think is the answer?

Comment: $a,b,c,d$ are propositional formulae or propositional variables ? In the second case, the result is straightforward: $a \to d$ can be a tautology only if $a=d$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately a,b,c,d  are propositional formulae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a,b,c,d$ are formulae, we can show that it does not hold, manufacturing a simple counterexample.

Consider as $d$ the formula: $a \land b \land c$; clearly:

> $a,b,c \vDash a \land b \land c$

but $a \nvDash a \land b \land c$, and the same for $b$ and $c$.